# Apache poi cant find method of log4j org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger.atDebug()

Tags: java, apache-poi, log4j

When I tried to read an excel file this error shows:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger.atDebug()Lorg/apache/logging/log4j/LogBuilder;
```

pointing to this line:

```
try (FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(configFile.getPath());
                        XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(inputStream)) {
```

I tried to exclude the log4j dependency from the apache poi but it's now working:

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.2</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.2</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
```

It seems apache poi version 5.2.2 uses or calls the log4j. Do I also need to included it to my dependency? or is there proper way to exclude log4j?

Comment: `log4j-core` is **not** a dependency of Apache POI, so the exclusion is a no-op. Please check with `mvn dependency:list`, which version of `log4j-api` is your application using. It is probably too old.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger` is part of `org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api`. If you are excluding `org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-core`, it will also exclude `org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api`

You need to have `log4j-api` in your classpath.

If you are using slf4j you can find the [log4j-over-slf4j](https://www.slf4j.org/legacy.html#log4j-over-slf4j)

More information on [Apache POI's Logging Framework](https://poi.apache.org/components/logging.html)